# Java Spring MVC Redirect with Regular expression

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc, redirect

So I have this redirect view one of my controllers:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/shoes", "/shoes/"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    public RedirectView shoesHome(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new RedirectView("https://www.somewebsite.com/");
    }
```

Is it possible to add a regular expression so that the redirect will happen for

> ```
> which currently is working fine and any other variation such as 
> http://mywebsites.com/shoes 
> http://mywebsites.com/shoes/sandals.html
> http://mywebsites.com/shoes/boots.html
> http://mywebsites.com/shoes/sport/nike.html
> ```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what you are expecting.

Comment: So right now if I go to mywebsite.com/shoes it will redirect to somewbsite.com but if I type somewebsite.com/shoes/sandals.html it will not, it will still go to .shoes/sandals.html. Is it possible to use a regular expression so every request that contains shoes/ will still redirect to somewebsite.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:-

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/shoes/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public RedirectView shoesHome() {
    return new RedirectView("https://www.somewebsite.com/");
}
```

With this, any URI after `/shoes` will also get redirected to `http://somewebsite.com`.

Here are the testcases:-

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath*:springtest-test.xml"})
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter;

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

    @Test
    public void testRedirect() throws Exception {
        assertRedirect("/shoes");
    }

    @Test
    public void testRedirect2() throws Exception {
        assertRedirect("/shoes/sandals.html");
    }

    @Test
    public void testRedirect3() throws Exception {
        assertRedirect("/shoes/sports/nike.html");
    }

    private void assertRedirect(String uri) throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest("GET", uri);
        MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();

        Object handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getHandler();
        ModelAndView modelAndView = handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, handler);

        RedirectView view = (RedirectView) modelAndView.getView();
        assertEquals("matching URL", "https://www.somewebsite.com/", view.getUrl());
    }
}
```